# Count within Group if Multiple Criteria are Met

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data that comes in as a [customer number, attribute] pair looking like:

[image: data comes in as pairs in columns A and B]

and I'd like to count how many customers have attributes A and B. The data is actually a lot bigger and I'm trying to build a conflict matrix to show a count of customers with both attributes,

[image: this is what I'm trying to build]

So I'd like a array formula that fits in the cell

Using power query, I can pivot the table and make it look like

[image: Test table]

and build out my grid with:

{=SUM(IF(INDIRECT("Test["&B$26&"]")*INDIRECT("Test["&$A27&"]"),1,0))}

[image]

Which is a pretty working for now, but can get the same results from the original data?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your example data seems to change all the time, which is rather confusing. The last part I get, but the first part makes no sense?

Comment: @kztd actually the Output should,, Attributes in Row and Customers in Columns then you may use `COUNTIFS.`

Comment: I have 167 attributes, so putting every combination (A-B, A-C, ...) in countif's down the side is a non-option.